# When $\ln(1+y) = y + o(y)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, asymptotics, exponentiation

I was reading a proof which utilize the fact that: $\ln(1+y) = y + o(y)$
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/842557/160028

I'm not so sure what is the meaning of $\ln(1+y) = y + o(y)$.

**When is it true?**

shouldn't it be **asymptotically** true (**only**?) when $y\to0$? Because 
$$\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\ln(1 +y) = \ln(1) = 0 = \lim\limits_{y\to 0}y$$

Comment: The meaning of $\ln (1+y) = y + o(y)$ is that $$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\ln (1+y) - y}{y} = 0.$$ Or, in other words, $\ln (1+y) = y + \text{ terms that vanish faster than } y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case we have

$$f(x)=g(x)+o(g(x)),\quad \text{when}\; x\to a\in\overline{\Bbb R}\iff f(x)\sim_a g(x)$$
which's equivalent to (the case $a=\infty$ isn't very different)
$$\forall \epsilon>0,\;\exists \delta>0,\;|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-g(x)|
<\epsilon|g(x)| $$

and in the given case we have simply
$$\ln(1+y)=y+o(y)\iff\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}=1$$

Comment: Thank you. Isn't it also true when $y\to\infty$?

Comment: No at $\infty$ we have just
$$\ln(1+y)=o(y)$$

Answer (score 1):

It mean that around $0$, $\ln(1+y)$ and $y$ behave in the same way. And yes, $\lim_{y\to 0}\ln(1+y)=\lim_{y\to 0}y$. For exemple, to compute $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}$ you know that $\ln(1+y)=y+o(y)$ (we note also $\ln(1+y)\sim y$ if $y\to 0$) and so,

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y}{y}=1.$$